# Styling HTML with Javascript based on values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to style an HTML table row based on values in that row, but I am stuck on step 1 - styling it at all!

Here's the code I have:

```
<tr id="tablerow<%=j%>">
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("tablerow<%=j%>").style.backgroundColor = "red";
</script>
```

<%=j> is pulling a row number in from the loop that's loading the data from the Access database as it loads the table.

The table rows are not showing up as red!

Then later I am going to use some IF statements in Javascript to color the rows based on data from some of the elements:

```
var datecheck = new Date;
if (document.getElementById("confirmStatus<%=j%>").value=="P" && (document.getElementById("confirmYear<%=j%>").value < datecheck.getFullYear())) {
        document.getElementById("tablerow<%=j%>").style.backgroundColor = "LightCoral"; }
```

I was able to figure it out - thanks for the help!

Comment: First off, you're not closing your `<tr>` tag. Second, why not just do `<tr id="tablerow<%=j%>" style="background-color: red">`? Even better if you could make this work with a CSS stylesheet.

Comment: as there are many rows, and you might be adding same script tag multiple times with different ids, this is not the right way of doing it.. you can use other selectors to get the values in loop and add styling as per your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your JavaScript console?

Atleast it should be `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementByID`

Answer (score 0):

Your script execute too early - html not ready yet. Try

```
<tr id="tablerow<%=j%>">
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener('load',function(){
         document.getElementByID("tablerow<%=j%>").style.backgroundColor = "red";
     }
</script>
```

But it's ugly idea do it by js

Comment: @Mike ok, i change my answer

Answer (score 0):

I find it better to use custom attributes instead of string concatenation:

```
<tr data-dbid="<%=j%>" style="background-color:red">
  <td><input class="confirmYear" /></td>
  <td><input class="confirmStatus" /></td>
</tr>
```

Then use that when needed:

```
function checkRow(id) {
    var _tr = document.querySelector("[data-dbid=" + id + "]"),
        _confirmYear = _tr.querySelector(".confirmYear"),
        _confirmStatus = _tr.querySelector(".confirmStatus");

    if (_confirmYear.value === "P" && _confirmStatus.value < datecheck.getFullYear())
       _tr.style.backgroundColor = "LightCoral";

}

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    [].forEach.call(
       document.querySelectorAll("[data-dbid]"),
       function(el) { checkRow(el.dataset["dbid"]) }
    );
});
```